# Is it possible to implement an IBAction that executes when a UILabel's text property changes?

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction

This is hopefully really simple.

I'm building a basic calculator application to learn iOS and Swift, and I'm attempting to implement code for the clear button.

As the standard goes, the clear button (implemented with a basic UIButton) displays a "AC" when the display is already cleared (only contains a 0), and displays a "C" otherwise.

My first idea for implementing this is with an IBAction that executes whenever the UILabel display's text changes. Apparently, this is not an action already implemented for UILabel. Is there another way to create this IBAction, or should I take another approach?

Comment: You have already/probably have an IBAction for clearing the data, change the title of clear button to "C" in that. Implement textfieldshouldchange delegate method of UITextField and whenever user types a number change the button title to "AC"

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, however I do not feel this is the best solution, as it is cluttering my code with too many `clearButton.setTitle(...)` lines in functions that should be more concerned about accomplishing other things. There are also other cases that I cannot catch in an IBAction function, such as when the calculator evaluates an expression to equal zero. The display would change state from a value to zero, and there would not be a method to tell the clear button to change.

Answer (score 3):

Use KVO (key value Observing).

Generate notification whenever any key (UILabel's text property) referencing value changes.

Have a wide idea about it [here](http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/)

Answer (score 1):

`IBAction` is basically the simplified way of associating a method to events of controls you drop on your storyboard or xib.  It's just one way (out of 2 or 3) of wiring your view to your controller.

You should make all the buttons on your calculator call the same method and pass the pressed button as an argument, something like `(void)buttonPressed:(id)button` then check the pressed button to change the display value and set the (A)C button accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Found a really slick solution for my problem after some more tinkering!

```
@IBOutlet weak var clearButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        if display.text == "0" {
            clearButton.setTitle("AC", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        else {
            clearButton.setTitle("C", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

The only catch is that when the clear button is pressed when the title is "C", it does not automatically change to "AC". This is fixed with the following IBAction for the clear button:

```
@IBAction func clearTouchUpInside() {
    if clearButton.currentTitle == "AC" {
        calculator.clear()
    }
    display.text = "0"
    clearButton.setTitle("AC", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```